# Static Table in a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Pior Xcode 5.1, I had a Static Table view with two cells. I was simply using it in as the login form, username and password.

Now that I upgraded to Xcode 5.1 I am getting an error:
Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances

I found a few work arounds but they were all old a none of them helped me. My View Controller class is a subclass of the UIViewController class. I am also implementing the following two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell = self.tableViewCellUser;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = self.tableViewCellPassword;
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This was working perfectly, but for some reason Xcode 5.1 broke it... Using a container seem to be a overkill as I would need a new view controller just because of two properties...

Comment: Does the above code not work?

Comment: "this was working perfectly, but for some reason Xcode 5.1 broke it"

Comment: You need to use a table view controller and embed it in a container in your view controller

Comment: Broke it how? Please detail more information.

Comment: @MiloGosnell "Now that I upgraded to Xcode 5.1 I am getting an error: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances" this is how it broke it

Comment: @box86rowh Damn.. isn't there a work around? Using a container would require me a add a new class just to handle these two fields...

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only way. Unless you simulate the look of a static table view, e.g. an image with textfields overlayed, or the careful use of multiple UIViews.

Comment: You shouldn't be implementing any of the data source methods like numberOfRowsInSection, or cellForRowAtIndexPath: when using a table view with static cells. In any case, if you don't want to use a container, and can't use a UITableViewController, then use dynamic prototypes instead.

Answer (score 3):

Static cells are only valid in a UITableViewController. Not in a UITableView.
If you used the UITableview instead of the UItableViewController because the layout shouldn't be fullscreen than add a container view to the view you want to place it instead of the table view in the storyboard.
Create a tableViewController in the storyboard.
Control drag from the containerView to te TableViewController and release. select 'embed' from the popup.

Comment: Thanks. Nearly started to loose my shit but you reminded me of container views!

Answer (score 0):

> I am also implementing the following two methods:

Are you sure that your code included those methods when it was working? If you're using a static table, you shouldn't implement any of the data source methods. Look, it says so [right here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW27):

> **Note:** If a table view in a storyboard is static, the custom subclass of UITableViewController that contains the table view should
>   not implement the data source protocol. Instead, the table view
>   controller should use its viewDidLoad method to populate the table
>   view’s data.

I had similar trouble myself recently -- I created a static table and found that it didn't work (cells didn't show up properly) because I had inadvertently implemented the same methods that you have.

Also, as some of the comments indicate, you should be using an instance of `UITableViewController` or a subclass. It's hard to see why this might be a problem for you -- you can do anything in a table view controller that you can do in a regular old view controller.

Comment: Yup, 100% sure. I wasn't implemented the DataSourceDelegate but I had to implemente those two methods else the cells wouldn't show up. If i simply change the ViewController supercalss to UITableViewController I still get the error